# Socket to replace Php Curl for Server to Server communication?

Tags: php, performance, sockets

I'm currently facing an issue with server to server communication.
My current situation is that i have two servers, lets call it S1 and S2 both running PHP7 with Apache 2.4

The client (C) will connect from s1, then s1 will perform a curl request to request a specific information from s2.

problem is that when it reaches a certain level number of requests per second, the curl request will slow down significantly due to the connection waiting.

Is there any better solution that can persistently connect two servers together so there isn't any need to create a new TCP connection for every request?

I'm currently looking at Socket.IO but unsure if this is the right approach to my current problems.

So the solution i am thinking is something like this
Client <-http-> Php S1 <-http-> SocketIO S1 <----socket----> SocketIO S2 <-http-> PHP S2

Comment: You could use sockets, but you would loose them at the and of the HTTP request.  Can you open ports on S1 or S2, or back connect to a local port ?

Comment: yeah i can open the ports, but is socket.io the best way to go for this?

Comment: If you can open ports you can run your own php / python / ruby server. This way you can skip the HTTP server and open a persistent connection. Client <--socket--> PHP S1 <--socket--> PHP S2